# Cannot install gradle in Mac OS X x86_64

Tags: macos, gradle

I used Homebrew to install gradle. It finished without errors, but while running

> $ gradle

command in the terminal, it says:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>
> Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.dylib' for Mac OS X 
>      x86_64.

I also tried to manually install brew as described in this [post](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-install-gradle-in-os-x/). I tried with the gradle versions 4.3 and 4.5.

I also tried changing the folder (/usr/local/gradle/gradle-4.3) permissions to 777 as described in the second last post in this [discussion](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1493).

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I had created .gradle folder manually earlier in the $HOME directory and it did not have write permissions. I changed the permissions to 777 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It was very unusual when I installed gradle it created .gradle file rather than directory on my $home directory.

So I removed that .gradle file and ran gradle build, it worked for me.